# Recovering deleted files on macOS

Tags: data-recovery, macos, deleted-files

I have gone through couple of previously answered questions but couldn't find any thing which will work for me.

I used this command accidently on a wrong folder, which deleted some important files and scripts except *.sh files.

```
 find . -type f ! -name '*.sh' -delete
```

Is it possible to recover the files ?

Comment: You might try with `testdisk` from a live Linux DVD but success is not guaranteed at all.

Comment: I avoid at all costs ever deleting via xargs or find, rather I'd prefer to create a list of what would have been deleted, print it out, and if I like i t, do it. It's just too easy to make mistakes using delete without having an intermediate step, sure, one liners are fun, but there's a time/place for them. Once the logic is tested, then it can be turned into a one liner for scripting purposes or whatever. Recovering data  is a real pain, it's still technically there until those locations on the disk have been overwritten, references to it have just been removed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have TimeMachine enabled then you can restore via the normal TimeMachine UI.

If you don't have TimeMachine enabled you may be able to use local snapshots to recover via the normal TimeMachine UI.

You can install photoreq from testdisk to look in the raw disk for script files, this is likely to turn up a lot of false positives.

Testdisk (inc Photoreq) downloads: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Download

Finally you should use this as warning and setup TimeMachine if you have not already, while it's not perfect it is far better than nothing.